# mathematical operators with strings

Tags: python

I have lists of value, like this:

```
p = [1, 2, 3]
s = [2, 3, 4]
```

and I when I make subtraction,

```
print p -s
```

it gives me the error.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

Can someone help?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: If you add two lists together you get a new list which contains the elements of both lists. What are you expecting subtraction of two lists to do?

Comment: Note that this *would* work with `numpy` arrays.

Comment: Your title mentions strings, but there are no strings in your code...

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to subtract corresponding elements between the two lists, and generate a new list with the result, try:

```
>>> p = [1, 2, 3]
>>> s = [2, 3, 4]
>>> [x-y for x,y in zip(p,s)]
[-1, -1, -1]
```